# py2app add multiple libraries to setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, py2app

I used `tkinter, pytube and os` libraries in my project. I found a `setup.py` example but I don't how to add my libraries to setup file. Can anybody help me? This is the example file:

```
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['pomodoro.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
'argv_emulation': True,
'iconfile': 'icon.icns',
'plist': {
'CFBundleShortVersionString': '0.2.0',
'LSUIElement': True,
},
'packages': ['rumps'],
}
setup(
app=APP,
name='Pomodoro',
data_files=DATA_FILES,
options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
setup_requires=['py2app'], install_requires=['rumps']
)
```

Comment: Don't you just need to add `tk` (tkinter pip package name) and `pytube` to `install_requires` list (`os` is built-in library) so you would get `install_requires=['rumps', 'tk', 'pytube']` ? You can read more regarding `install_requires` [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)

Comment: @taxevader `pip install tk` doesn't install `tkinter`, it installs "*TensorKit is a deep learning helper between Python and C++*" See https://pypi.org/project/tk/ . One cannot declare `tkinter` as a dependency, it's a part of the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Comment: @phd Oh you're right, my mistake. So it should be `install_requires=['rumps', 'pytube']`

Comment: @taxevader I made the app but when I click on it nothing is showing up, only a opening animation appears.